# Regular expression library that returns all matches for multiple patterns in one run for C++?

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I'm looking for a regular expression (or something else) library for C++ that would allow me to specify a number of patterns, run on a string and return the matching locations of all patterns.

For example:
Patterns {"abcd", "abcd"}
String {"abcd abce abcd"}

Result:
abcd matches: 0-3, 11-14
abce matches: 5-9

Anyone know of a such a library?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend boost::xpressive http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/xpressive.html.

One of possible solution:

```
string text = "abcd abce abcd";

static const sregex abcd = as_xpr("abcd");  // static - faster
sregex abce = sregex::compile( "abce" )  // compiled 
sregex all = *(keep(abcd) | keep(abce));

smatch what;

if( regex_match( text, what, all ) ) 
{
    smatch::nested_results_type::const_iterator begin = what.nested_results().begin();
    smatch::nested_results_type::const_iterator end = what.nested_results().end();

    for(;it != end; it++)
    {
        if(it->regex_id() == abcd.regex_id())
        {
            // you match abcd
            // use it->begin() and it->end()
            // or it->position() and it->length()
            continue;
        }
        if(it->regex_id() == abce.regex_id())
        {
            // you match abcd...
            continue;
        };

}
```

I think is not best solution, you could check “Semantic Actions and User-Defined Assertions” in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are part of the standard extension tr1 and implemented in a number of standard libraries (i.e. [dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com))

I think that its very straightforward to write the surrounding code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work with an simple **or**?

```
"abcd|abcd"
```

which is a valid regular expression.

Comment: A simple or will find me only "abcd" OR "abce" and it's locations.
So in the above case, it will only find the locations of abcd.

Comment: No, or (alteration) of abcd|abce should find all locations that abcd or abce match.